# llaves primarias, no repetir 2 datos en lenguaje C

Tags: c

tengo un problema en este codigo que estoy haciendo, se trata de hacer un registro de varios datos de una persona y mostrarlos y ya tengo las 2 opciones pero le quiero agregar llasves primarias al registro para que cuando el usuario ingrese un dato que sea igual a otro le aparezca un mensaje de que ya existe dicha clave unica y se salga del registro.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void registro();
void mostrar();

struct datos{
  int numprestamo;
  char nombre[10];
  char direccion[10];
  int telefono;
  float importesoli;
} datos[10];

int x=0;
char busqueda;
int k,j,aux;
char auxn[10];

//char ap[20] ="existe este dato";

int main(void){
  char opcion;
  
  do{
    printf("\nCasa de empeño: Gran estafa\n");
    printf("A) Registro de prestamos\n");
    printf("B) Consulta general\n");
    printf("C) salir del programa\n");
    printf("Opcion: ");
    scanf("%s",&opcion);//Menu de eleccion, se elegiran la opcion que desea con la variable opcion
    
    switch(opcion){

      case 'A':     
        registro();//Esta opcion registrara datos de una persona
      break;

      case 'B':
        mostrar();//Esta opcion mostrara los datos registrados de una persona ordenados alfabeticamente
      break;
    }    
  }while(opcion!='C');

}
```

funcion de registro:

```
void registro(){
  char continuar;
  int y;
  
  do{
    printf("\n********Registro*********\n");
    printf("Numero de prestamo: ");
    scanf("%d", &datos[x].numprestamo);
```

codigo que intento hacer para crear una clave unica para el numero de prestamo(esta unido a la funcion registro)

```
    for(y=0;y<x;y++){ 
      if (datos[x].numprestamo==datos[y].numprestamo) {
        datos[y].numprestamo = datos[x].numprestamo;
        }else{
        printf("Este numero ya existe\n");
        break;
        }
      break;
    }
    
    printf("Nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", datos[x].nombre);  
    printf("Direccion: ");
    scanf("%s", datos[x].direccion);
    printf("Telefono: ");
    scanf("%d", &datos[x].telefono);
    printf("Importe solicitado: ");
    scanf("%f", &datos[x].importesoli);
    x++;
    
    printf("Ingresar otro registro? s/n: ");
    scanf("%s", &continuar);
    
  }while(continuar!='n');
  
}
```

funcion para mostrar registro

```
void mostrar(){
  
  printf("\n***Consulta general***\n");

  for (k=1;k<x;k++){
    for (j=0;j<x-1;j++){
      if(strcmp(datos[j].nombre,datos[j+1].nombre)>0){
            
        strcpy(auxn,datos[j].nombre);
        strcpy(datos[j].nombre,datos[j+1].nombre);          
        strcpy(datos[j+1].nombre,auxn);

        strcpy(auxn,datos[j].direccion);
        strcpy(datos[j].direccion,datos[j+1].direccion);          
        strcpy(datos[j+1].direccion,auxn);
               
        aux = datos[j].numprestamo;   
        datos[j].numprestamo = datos[j+1].numprestamo;
        datos[j+1].numprestamo = aux;
        
        aux = datos[j].telefono;   
        datos[j].telefono = datos[j+1].telefono;
        datos[j+1].telefono = aux;

        aux = datos[j].importesoli;   
        datos[j].importesoli = datos[j+1].importesoli;
        datos[j+1].importesoli = aux;
                               
      }                
    }
  }
 
  for(j=0;j<x;j++){
    printf("\nNombre: %s\n", datos[j].nombre);
    printf("Direccion: %s\n", datos[j].direccion);
    printf("Numero de prestamo: %d\n", datos[j].numprestamo);
    printf("Telefono: %d\n", datos[j].telefono);
    printf("Importe solicitado: %f\n", datos[j].importesoli);    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren varias opciones, pero dado que C, a diferencia de C++, no está orientado a objetos y no es posible implementar el operador == para esa estructura (sería lo ideal si trabajaras con un objeto) creo que lo mejor es guardar cada una de las claves en un array auxiliar y se compruebe en cada vez que hagas el registro.

El costo computacional es elevado, ya que piensa que estás trabajando en memoria y no tienes una unidad de persistencia donde almacenar dichas claves, por lo que cada vez que compruebes, necesitas verificar que la clave no está en dicho array.

Tal y como lo tienes en la función de registro creo que no está mal encaminado, teniendo en cuenta que estás programando con un lenguaje de bajo nivel.